# How to return Django User that is subclassed from the custom user after auth has been successful?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to return user information after authentication is successful. However, the user information I want isn't in the custom `MyUser` model, but in the users that extend from `MyUser`, such as `Player`

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Player(MyUser):
    national_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

This is how I create a user that is a `Player` and provide it with a token

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        player = Player.objects.create(**validated_data)
        player.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        player.save()
        token = Token.objects.create(user=player)
        return player
```

I have successfully implemented `CustomAuthToken` class to be able to log in a user, get their token and additional info back. [This substitutes the simple token retrieval with obtain_auth_token](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/):

```
class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'user_id': user.pk,
            'email': user.email,
        })
```

This, however, returns information from the `MyUser` model, and not the `Player` model, which is what I'm trying to achieve.

I've tried:

```
return Response({
     'token': token.key,
     'user': PlayerSerializer(user).data
     })
```

but got this error

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `national_id` on serializer `PlayerSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `MyUser` instance.
Original exception text was: 'MyUser' object has no attribute 'national_id'
```

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do with the `ObtainAuthToken` class?

Comment: To get additional info besides the token. edited question.